# ConvertFrom-JSON takes a of time, CPU and memory for larger files (file size: 180 MB)

Tags: powershell

`$json_data = $json_string | ConvertFrom-Json`

The statement works fine for smaller strings. But it doesn't even complete for larger strings of size 180MB.

Is there any workaround for parsing JSON without converting to PSCustomObject?

or is there any C# code to do JSON parsing which I can embed in Powershell?

When the string is dumped to a file, it comes around 180MB.

Please check the response tab of Retrieve Export section which explains the format of json.
https://api.kennasecurity.com/data-export-docs

```
PS /Users/gsubrama> $jsondata = Get-Content -Raw -Path "/Users/gsubrama/Documents/ss_copy.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
PS /Users/gsubrama> $jsondata.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

The type still shows String. But for smaller files the type changes to PSCustomObject

Comment: A number of things could be at play here, including the json data structure. Can you describe it, or perhaps provide a sample? You also state in the title that your *file size* is 180MB, but in the question you write that you have a 180MB *string*. Please clarify (and provide the full code if you're reading from a file first)

Comment: If your json object is actually 180MB... You have other problems (like, wrong tool for the job)

Comment: I've edited my post..  please let me know if u have any doubts
@MathiasR.Jessen .

Comment: @GANESHKUMARSV Why would you call `ConvertFrom-Json` twice?

Comment: As you can see ConvertFrom-Json doesn't change the datatype.. It still shows the name as string

Comment: Probably relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/13989994/3820185

Comment: @wiesion that worked! thanks :)