# Convert CSV file to JArray

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I have a need to export the json results of a Invoke-WebRequest call to a .CSV file so that non-technical users can edit the data.  This is what the json looks like when I save it to a .CSV file:

```
{
  "Forecasts": [
    {
      "AccountNumber": "12345",
      "Period": "2022-02-01T00:00:00",
      "Field1": 3998.87968239,
      "Field2": 2133.91206875
    },
    {
      "AccountNumber": "12346",
      "Period": "2022-03-01T00:00:00",
      "Field1": 6741.483,
      "Field2": 4007.857
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm creating the .CSV file with this line of code:

```
$json.Forecasts | ForEach-Object { $_ | Export-Csv -path $fileName -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force }
```

And this is working good.  After the user edits the data and saves and closes the .CSV file, I need to convert the .CSV data back into a JArray that looks like the original json structure (like above) so I can make another Invoke-WebRequest call (Patch), passing the JArray as the Body.

When I execute this line of code:

```
$editedJson = Get-Content -Raw -Path "$fileName" | ConvertFrom-CSV | Select-Object -Property AccountNumber,Period,Field1,Field2 | ConvertTo-json
```

The json looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "AccountNumber":  "12345",
        "Period":  "2022-02-01T00:00:00",
        "Field1":  "3900.87968239",
        "Field2":  "2100.91206875"
    },
    {
        "AccountNumber":  "12346",
        "Period":  "2022-03-01T00:00:00",
        "Field1":  "6700.483",
        "Field2":  "4000.857"
    }
]
```

As you can see, it's missing the "Forecasts" portion of the JArray and I don't know how to get the .CSV data back into this format. Can anyone help with this ?

Comment: The other difference is that all your numbers are now strings. There are no data types in CSV, that's why everything is taken for a string initially. To achieve true parity of your output array, you need to explicitly cast the affected fields in each record to `[double]` before calling `ConvertTo-Json`. The same idea applies to other data types.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to create an object with that property (`Forecasts`) and attach the imported CSV to said property:

```
# This line would be where you import the CSV:
# $csv = Import-Csv ..... 
$csv = @'
"AccountNumber","Period","Field1","Field2"
"12345","2/1/2022 12:00:00 AM","3998.87968239","2133.91206875"
"12346","3/1/2022 12:00:00 AM","6741.483","4007.857"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

@{
    Forecasts = $csv
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

If you want to assure that the JSON representation of `Forecasts` is always an *array* (even when the CSV only has one row):

```
@{
    Forecasts = [array]$csv
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I had a hard time with the here-string, but figured it out.  I'm getting the following exception:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : {"Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains an invalid entry for parameter 'body' for method 
'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage HttpPatchForecast(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray, System.String)' in 
'....forecast.ForecastController'. The dictionary contains a value of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject', but the parameter requires a 
value of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'."}
```

Comment: @ILoveMarcyGirl no problem. I would advise you to ask a new question regarding this error message, adding the information used for the web request

Comment: @ILoveMarcyGirl Perhaps also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13968004/9898643) on how to parse JSON into a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray`

Comment: @Theo It was a hack, but I was able to get the API to recognize the body as a JArray with these lines:

$editedJson = @{Forecasts = [array]$csv} | ConvertTo-Json
$editedJson = "[" + "$editedJson" + "]"